# How can one create a variable to hold class instance with <TSource> using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a class that requires an object to be passed in order to create a new instance of it like. My class looks like so

```
public class TableMapper<TSource>
{
   ........
}
```

When I make a new instance of it I do the following.

```
private readonly TableMapper<Client> Mapper; // Client is an instance of a EF model.
```

Now, I want to create an instance of it as a variable in a new class. So my new class will look something like the following

```
// The syntax below is incorrect!!
public class IReportRelation
{
    TableMapper<TSource> localMapper { get; set; } //incorrect usage

    Func<string, string> localProperty { get; set;}

    Func<string, string> foreignProperty { get; set; }

    TableMapper<TSource> foreignMapper { get; set; } //incorrect usage
}
```

Yet from another class named `TableMapper`, I need a method that will  create an instance of `IReportRelation` class from within a method like so

```
public IReportRelation Relation<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> lProperty, TableMapper<TSource> fMapper, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> fKey)
{
    return new IReportRelation { localProperty = lProperty; foreignMapper = fMapper; foreignProperty = fKey};

}
```

I am hoping I can call my `Relation` method with something like so

```
public override List<IReportRelation> ReportRelations
        {
            get
            {
                new List<IReportRelation>
                {
                    Mapper.Relation(x => x.ClientId, TableMapper<Client>, c => c.Id),
                };
            }
        }
```

How can I correctly create that have a property that holds an instance of another class where  will be what every I pass to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `IReportRelation` -interface to the following:

```
public class IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>
{
    public TableMapper<TLocal> localMapper { get; set; }

    public Func<string, string> localProperty { get; set; }

    public Func<string, string> foreignProperty { get; set; }

    public TableMapper<TForeign> foreignMapper { get; set; }
}
```

With two different generic parameters, you can differ between source and target

EDIT:

```
public IReportRelation<T1, T2> Relation<T1, T2>(TableMapper<T1> lMapper, Func<string, string> lProperty, TableMapper<T2> fMapper, Func<string, string> fKey)
    {
        return new IReportRelation<T1, T2> { localMapper = lMapper, localProperty = lProperty, foreignMapper = fMapper, foreignProperty = fKey };
    }
```

I highly recommend you also, not to prefix a class with **I**.  `IReportRelation` indicates, its an Interface

**Usage**:

```
public void SomeMethod(){                
            var xx = this.Relation(new TableMapper<Student>(), dummy, new TableMapper<Department>(), dummy);
        }

        string dummy(string xx)
        {
            return xx + "Hello";
        }
```

Comment: What should TLocal and TForeign do here?

Comment: If you want to use generics in an interface, the interface must know the types to expect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Then how would my Relation method create this class? I tried something like this but I am getting lots of error `public IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign> Relation<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> lProperty, TableMapper<TSource> fMapper, Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> fProperty)
 {
  return new IReportRelation<this, fMapper> { localProperty = lProperty, foreignProperty = fProperty};
 }`

Comment: Thank a lot. Do you mind helping me understand what `Relation<T1, T2>` are for? Also, should `foreignMapper = fMapper` be removed from the code? wouldn't the class will automatically know both instances of `TableMapper`?

Comment: @Jaylen Did another Update. It depends on your usage of the Mapper if the Relation should know both of the mappers. There's i dont get. If you are using EntityFramework, why do you need such a mapper?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116311/discussion-between-jaylen-and-lokusking).